# Migration not working on production server, using Laravel Forge, with error [RuntimeException] Aborted

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I'm just in the process of setting up my first Laravel Forge server. Everything seems to have gone well, the code has been pulled from my Git repo and I can see my website online. For some reason, the database migration isn't working.

When I run the 'Deploy' command through Forge, the error I'm seeing in the Forge event log is:

```
From repohost:myusername/myrepo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
Compiling views
Migration table created successfully.



  [RuntimeException]  
  Aborted             



migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

I've tried running the `migrate` (and `migrate:refresh`) command through the terminal and it just hangs and I have to eventually CTRL-C out (even when using `--verbose`). When I inspect the database after, only the migrations table has been created, and it is empty.

I've also tried re-running all my migrations on my development environment (Homestead) and they work fine.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting a bunch of different problems here, and will probably need to do some more debugging before anyone can help you.  Also, forge is the "optimized for Laravel hosting, right?" -- I'd try hitting up their support.  That's what you're paying for after all.

First, the exception thrown: `[RuntimeException]` Aborted.

In a stock Laravel install, the only exceptions that throw an "Aborted" message come from the Symfony Console components that artisan is based on. Specifically, in the `ask` and `doAsk` methods inside of the following files/class definitions

```
vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DialogHelper.php
vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php
```

Specifically, the Symfony components throw these exceptions when `artisan` has trouble reading responses from the command

```
#File:     vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DialogHelper.php

    if (null === $autocomplete || !$this->hasSttyAvailable()) {
        $ret = fgets($inputStream, 4096);
        if (false === $ret) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Aborted');
        }
        $ret = trim($ret);
    }
```

These are pretty hard bugs to track down, and may have to do with too much input returned by the script (say, a giant stack trace), invalid input that PHP can't handle, some problem with the terminal application you're using to connect to the server, or the way the server itself it configured.

i.e. The exception probably has nothing to do with your actual error.

Based on the behavior, it sounds like of of your migrations throw an stack trace your terminal can't handle, **or** creates a database deadlock.  It's tedious, but I'd

1. Isolate and reproduce the problem on a non-production server
2. Drop you database
3. Move your migrations to a sub folder
4. Add each migration back, one by one, and try to run it

Eventually you'll find the migration that's causing the problem, and can debug from there.

Comment: Yeah, I found it difficult to trace as there doesn't seem to be anything in the log either. Could it be a memory issue on the server? I added the database structure manually then the migrations command worked (obviously, with no migration to run). I'll try your suggestions to see if it's a specific migration.